# How to get value of integer template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

title might be confusing, but lets say I have a template:

```
template <typename T, size_t offset>
struct offsetedIdxArray
{
//...
}
```

And after I create an instance:

```
static const size_t offset(1701);
offsetedIdxArray<zmq::socket_t, offset> oia;
```

Is there a way to get offset variable from `oia`. I know I can just use offset but from code style perspective i prefer to get it from `oia` if possible.

EDIT: I'm looking for a way to get offset without helper variable inside struct...

Comment: I don't think there is anyother way , either you use offset directly or go with luchian

Comment: @Mr.Anubis there is, see my answer.

Comment: @juanchopanza yes it is, but it's more verbose , isn't it?

Comment: @Mr.Anubis it is just a simple function call that returns the desired number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to obtain the information from an `offsetedIdxArray<T,N>` object without adding any members to the class template, you can use a template function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T, size_t offset>
struct offsetedIdxArray
{
};

template <typename T, size_t offset>
size_t getOffset(const offsetedIdxArray<T, offset>&) {
  return offset;
}

int main()
{
   offsetedIdxArray<int,5> oia;
   std::cout << getOffset(oia) << "\n";

}
```

Otherwise you can add a static constant or enum data member, as suggested in other posts.

Answer (score 3):

```
template <typename T, size_t offset>
struct offsetedIdxArray
{
   static const size_t off = offset;
//...
};
```

and get the variable `off`.

Comment: Yeah, I just edited my Q to say that I would like to get it for free, aka without having another variable. But if this is the only way Ill accept your A.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl in the question, you said you want to get it from `oia`. How do you expect to achieve that without any members?

Comment: it is template param, so compiler knows it at compile time... question is if he is willing to share knowledge. :D

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl you can get it without members, at the cost of a template function. See my answer.

Comment: why do you put static and const ?

Comment: @yes123 so you can initialize it inside the class definition & because `off` is the same for the same specializations, so there's no point in having it in all objects of that type.